# what're the proper DNS record settings for google apps so that my site hosted on another company can send email that won't consider spam

Tags: email-server, web-hosting, mx-record, g-suite, shared-hosting

I'm using Google apps email and I have a website that's hosted on shared hosting company.

How should I configure the DNS records so that incoming mail will get to Google but at the same time email send from the website (by a form) will pass the reverse IP check and won't considered spam?

Comment: Your MX record is for _incoming_ mail only. It's not relevant to sending mail from your domain. If you're having a problem sending mail, you should instead ask about that.

Comment: @Alex:  I made edits to ask the correct question.  This is likely a duplicate or near duplication of other question.

Answer (score 2):

The MX record(s) need to point to Google's mail servers.  The Google Apps Administrator site provides the [MX records to use](https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125?hl=en).  However, they are not relevant to the sending of email.

If you are not sending email via Google apps, then:

- The mail server needs a static IP address.
- THe mail server should have an A record for its domain.  Its domain would normally be of the form `smtp.example.com` or `mail.example.com` returning its static IP address.
- The mail IP address needs a pointer returning the domain of the mail server.  (You will likely have to get your ISP to do this for you.)
- The mail server should use its domain name in its HELO message.
- The domain used for your from addresses should have an SPF record of the form `v=spf1 ipv4:192.0.2.5 include:_spf.google.com ~all`.  (Replace 192.0.2.5 with your servers IP address.)
- Consider adding an SPF record like `v=spf1 A -all` to the mail server's domain.
- Consider adding an SPF record like `v=spf1 -all` for domains which should not be originating mail, like your web server (www) domain.